# Parsing XML with apostrophe

Tags: java, xml

Taking the BBC News RSS feed for example, one of their news items is as follows:

```
<item><title>Pupils 'bullied on sports field'</title><description>bla bla..
```

I have some java code parsing this - however, when a title contains an apostrophe (as above), the parsing stops, so I end up with the following title: **Pupils '** and then it continues on and parses the description (which is fine). How do I get it to parse the full title? The following is a segment of code from inside my for loop where I parse the info:

```
                    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                    tmp.setTitle(getCharacterDataFromElement(line).toString());
```

The exact same code is used to parse the other elements like description and pubDate etc, which are all fine.

This is the getCharacterDataFromElement method:

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = ((Node) e).getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I use the DocumentBuilder, DocumentBuilderFactory and org.w3c.dom to work with the RSS Feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As davidfrancis suggested, you should iterate over all children in `getCharacterDataFromElement()`.

Alternatively, if you can use DOM level 3, you can use the [Node.getTextContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) method instead which does what you want.

```
NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
Element line = (Element)title.item(0);
tmp.setTitle(line.getTextContent());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your getCharacterDataFromElement only looks at the first child - see if there are further child elements too and tack all the text together

HTH - DF

Answer (score -1):

Well, AFAIK, apostrophe is a reserved character in XML and thus should be encoded as `&apos;`.

This means the BBC News RSS feed doesnt provide well-formatted XML.

The best thing would be to issue a bug report to the BBC News RSS feed provider so that they fix it.